# Regex negation pattern match

Tags: c, regex-negation

I have three string samples below:

```
day/Mon/done
day/Tue/done
day/Wed/done
```

How do I extract `day/Wed/done` using negation for the other two? Below doesn't work.

```
/day/[^(Mon|Tue)]/done
```

Comment: if you look towards the right side of this page for "related", you will probably see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word?rq=1

Comment: Not a C question - suggest removing tag.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for pointing to the link.

Comment: @chux: The C tag is relevant if it implies that OP intends to usre a posix-compatible regex library. (i.e. no negative lookahead).

Answer (score 1):

It's not how negated [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) work -- they still interpret each character inside the `[..]` as a single character. And there is no match for

```
day/?/done
```

where `?` is only one character. Either use any of the techniques in [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word?rq=1) (thanks, Peter!), or make good use of the fact that the first character for these days are unique:

```
day/[^MT]../done
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
'day/(?!(Mon|Tue)).*/done'
```

Comment: The OP *wants* to match `Wed` (or, more precisely, neither `Mon` nor `Tue`).